# Regular expression problem, avoid the first sign, and get the second one

Tags: regex, string, match, expression

I have a small problem. I try to extract some matches from a string, like this. But I don't know how to do this. Thanks

`2+22` -> match1: **2**; match2: **22**

`2-22` -> match1: **2**; match2: **22**

`2++22` -> match1: **2**; match2: **+22**

`2+-22` -> match1: **2**; match2: **-22**

Comment: Please explain if the examples you have are what you're looking for or what you're getting. Also, please provide what you've done so far (and what language you've used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what language you are using, but the following seems to work for those test cases using PHP/PCRE:

```
(\d+)[+-]([+-]?\d+)
```

To break it down:

- `(\d+)` match at least one digit, and capture it in group 1
- `[+-]` match either a plus or minus
- `([+-]?\d+)` match either a plus or minus or nothing, followed by at least one digit. Capture the whole thing in group 2.